# Process.Start() doesn't redirect after deploying on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, live, process.start

I'm using a project that uses Process.start() to redirect to live web OAuth for request token 
after deploying the site on a local IIS server it stopped working and it doesn't do any redirection 
here's my code

```
authorizeUri.AppendFormat("?client_id={0}&", appId);
    authorizeUri.AppendFormat("scope={0}&", "wl.signin");
    authorizeUri.AppendFormat("response_type={0}&", "token");
    authorizeUri.AppendFormat("redirect_uri={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://scarnetdomain.com/Default3.aspx/"));
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = authorizeUri.ToString();
    Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score 11):

**A web server is not your desktop**.

Process.Start will start a process on the machine the code is running on. So in your code it will start a process on the IIS server. As an added bonus, depending on how you've configured IIS and the account it is running as it's likely that there's no desktop access so starting a process which spawns a browser is at best going to fail and at worse going to start IE and leave it there, taking up memory.

Please use one of the existing OAuth libraries like [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/) or the built-in support in [MVC4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc) or [MVC5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on)